# Call variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Apologies for this simple question, but I tried various approach without success.

This is my vars file

```yaml
---
preprod:
  name: nginx
prod:
  name: apache
```

I am trying to pass the value of `name` based on the environment name user provides (preprod, prod etc).
This is my template

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ env.name }} 
  name: {{ env.name }}
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ env.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ env.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: {{ env.name }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: {{ env.name }}
        resources: {}
```

However, when I try with this using following command:

```sh
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e env=preprod
```

I am getting the following error.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'"}
```

My expectation is the `{{ env.name }}` should have been replaced with the value of `preprod.name` as in `nginx` in this case.

I want users to provide the value for `env` via `-e` on the command line, it seems if I do like `preprod.name` directly on the template, it seems to work, but I don't want that.

I hope this clarifies what I am trying to do, but it didn't work.
May I know what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message indicates that the extra var passed on command line as `-e` is a string, and not the key (we expect) of the dict we are loading from the vars file.

I'm making up an example playbook as you have not shown how you load your vars file. I'm using `include_vars` as we can name the variable to load dict into.

```yaml
    # include vars with a name, so that we can access testvars[env]
    - include_vars:
        file: testvars.yml
        name: testvars
    - template:
        src: test/deployment.yaml.j2
        dest: /tmp/deployment.yaml
      vars:
        _name: "{{ testvars[env]['name'] }}"
```

With this approach, the `prod` and `preprod` keys will be available under `testvars`, and can be referenced with a variable such as `env`.

Then the template should use `_name` variable, like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ _name }}
```

Comment: Taking a cue from @Vladimir Botka's answer - using [separate inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/intro_inventory.html), with the appropriate app name in the `group_vars/<groupname>` file will be the simplest solution. This will also eliminate the need to pass environment name as extra vars.

Answer (score 2):

Given the variables in a place where the play can find it, e.g. group_vars/all. Optionally add *default_env*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
preprod:
  name: nginx
prod:
  name: apache
default_env:
  name: lighttpd
```

Use *vars* [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) to *`"Retrieve the value of an Ansible variable".`* See

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    env: "{{ lookup('vars', my_env|default('default_env')) }}"
    app: "{{ env.name }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: app
```

by default displays

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
...
  app: lighttpd
```

Now you can select the environment by declaring the variable *my_env*, .e.g

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e my_env=prod
...
  app: apache
```

and

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e my_env=preprod
...
  app: nginx
```

Comment: Nice idea! The `group_vars` implementation would be the simplest.